# Bootstrap Popover "auto" placement incorrectly applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, openlayers-3

**Background:**
I'm using OpenLayers **V3** to display a map with multiple "markers/icon" to mark the location of addresses that I want to display on the map. I'm using javascript to display a popover anytime the user hovers over one of the markers (fyi "marker" popover displays the street address for the marker location). You'll see that I'm setting the bootstrap popover placement value to "auto top" to ensure that any popovers near the edge of the map will be displayed so that they don't run off the edge of the map (i.e., get cutoff).

**Problem:**
When one of the markers is near the top edge of the map the "auto top" placement setting correctly adjust the placement for that "marker's" popover so that it remains visible (i.e., popover displays at the bottom of the marker) but unfortunately all other "markers" on the map needlessly seemed to have "inherited" this "bottom placement". As a result this causes the "marker's"  near the bottom of the page to have their popover cutoff.

**Sample javacript code:**

Note: There is a lot of code here but I thought it would be better to include it all rather than leave out something that might be relevent to solving the issue. Also, I should note that the javascript is "fed" an object that looks as follows:

> ```
> {'pintype1.filename.png':
> ["Address", [Longitude,Latitude]],
> ["Address", [Longitude,Latitude]],
> etc., etc.
> 'pintype2.filename.png':
> ["Address", [Longitude,Latitude]],
> ["Address", [Longitude,Latitude]]
> etc., 
> etc.,
> }
> ```

The nested loops in the drawmap javascript code are used to loop through this object and set/save values in the OpenLayers software.

> ```
> window.RentMyThing = window.RentMyThing || {}
> window.RentMyThing.drawMap = function drawMap (mapAttributesPlus) {
> var popuplabel = '';
> var iconLocations = [];
> var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
>  //create empty vector -- not sure if this is needed??????
> });
> $('.map').html('');
> // Outer Loop to retrieve each pin type
> Object.keys(mapAttributesPlus).forEach(function(pinType) {
>
>
>   // Inner Loop to retrieve all coordinates associated with each pin type
>   mapAttributesPlus[pinType].forEach(function(coords) {
>
>     var iconLocation = ol.proj.transform([coords[1][0], coords[1][1]], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
>     iconLocations.push(iconLocation)
>     popupLabel = coords[0]
>     console.log("Address: " + coords[0] + "Lon/Lat: " + coords[1][0] + ', ' + coords[1][1]);
>
>     var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
>       geometry: new ol.geom.Point(iconLocation),
>       // Added line for popup
>       name: popupLabel
>     })
>
>     // Create Pin styling
>     iconFeature.setStyle(
>       new ol.style.Style({
>         image: new ol.style.Icon({
>           anchor: [0.2, 1],
>           anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
>           anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
>           opacity: 0.75,
>           src: pinType  // Set pin type
>         })
>       })
>     )
>     iconFeature.on('mouseover', function() {alert('hover')})
>     vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
>   }) // End of inner loop - coords
> }); // End of outer loop - pinType
>
> // *************Create Vector Layer with Markers and Build Map ***************************
> var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
>   source: vectorSource //      style: iconStyle
> });
>
> var map = new ol.Map({
>   target: 'map',
>   layers: [
>     new ol.layer.Tile({
>       title: "Rental Proximity Map",
>       source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
>     }), vectorLayer],
>   view: new ol.View({
>    center: iconLocations[0],          // ??? Do i need a centering point at this point.
>     zoom: 12
>   }),
>   controls: ol.control.defaults({
>     attributionOptions: {
>       collapsible: false
>     }}).extend([
>       new ol.control.ScaleLine()
>     ])
> });
>
> // Bound the map if multiple points
>
> var view = map.getView()
> var extent = ol.extent.boundingExtent(iconLocations)
> var size = map.getSize()
> view.fitExtent(extent, size)
> // If only one coordinate then binding map on that one point will produce
> // a map that is zoomed in so close it will appear that no map is  displayed
> // so we want to prevent the map zoom from going to high hence "if statement below"
> if (view.getZoom() > 16) {
>   view.setZoom(16);
> }
>
> Window.map = map;
> // ***********************************************
> //  Popup logic
> // http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/icon.js
> // ***********************************************
>
> // The line below is required to get popup to appear
> var element = $('.popup').first();
>
> var popup = new ol.Overlay({
>   element: element,
>   positioning: 'auto top',
>   stopEvent: false
> });
> map.addOverlay(popup);
>
> var showing;
> // display popup on click
> map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
>   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
>       function(feature, layer) {
>         return feature;
>       });
>   if (feature) {
>     // Showing flag was added to remove popover from flickering when the mouse is hovered over the
>     // icon/marker and there is incidental/minor movement in the mouse. Setting the show flag ensures
>     // that you don't attempt to redraw the popup over and over (and get flickering) with minor mouse
>     // movements
>     if (! showing) {
>       showing = true;
>       var name = feature.get('name')
>       var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
>       var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
>
>       // Next line Added for testing
>       // var element = $('.popup').this
>       popup.setPosition(coord);
>
>       // The line below fixed the scenario where clicking on one marker (e.g., 'renter')
>       // and then immediately clicking on another marker (e.g, 'rental')  caused the wrong popup
>       // content to appear on the newly clicked marker (e.g., popup displayed 'renter' rather than
>       // rental). The line below uses jQuery method .attr to put the value of the newly clicked
>       // marker value (i.e., name) into the HTML in the location that bootstrap pull the
>       // the popup value (i.e., 'data-content')
>       $(element).attr('data-content', name)
>
>       $(element).popover({
>         'trigger': 'hover click',
>         'placement': 'auto top',
>         'html': true,
>         'content': name,
>         // Had to add container to make "auto" placement work properly
>       });
>       $(element).popover('show');
>     }
>   } else {
>     showing = false;
>     $(element).popover('destroy');
>   }
> });
>
> // change mouse cursor when over marker
> map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
>   if (e.dragging) {
>     $(element).popover('destroy');
>     return;
>   }
>   var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
>   var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
>   var target = document.getElementById(map.getTarget());
>   target.style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
> });   } // End of drawmap function
> ```

**Relevant HTML:**

> ```
> <div id="map" class="map">
>   <div class="popup" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title="" data-placement=""></div>
> </div>
> ```

**Relevent CSS:**

> ```
> div#map {
>   height: 400px;
>   width: 512px;
> }
>
> .popover{
>     width:160px;
>     height:70px;
> }
> ```

Trying to identify why I'm seeing the behavior noted above in **Problem Summary**.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`'auto top'` is not a valid placement option for an `ol.Overlay`. Valid options are `'bottom-left'`, `'bottom-center'`, `'bottom-right'`, `'center-left'`, `'center-center'`, `'center-right'`, `'top-left'`, `'top-center'`, `'top-right'`. To make sure that your popover is visible, you may want to configure your `ol.Overlay` with the `autoPan` option set to true. So a valid overlay configuration would look like this:

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: element,
  autoPan: true,
  positioning: 'center-center',
  stopEvent: false
});
```

Your Popover code could be simplified quite a bit. Maybe you want to take a look at the official OpenLayers 3 + Bootstrap Popover example for inspiration: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/overlay.html.

Comment: @tsauerwein Are you sure? I think when the popover positioning is not set to anything auto, it should work.